# How to disable #hashtag in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My JQM includes three `data-role="page"`.

The issue:

Now I go to another **page2** from the default home **page1**, so the URL is `localhost/index.php#page2`. When I refresh the page, it is still in **page2**.

Is that a way that it can go back to `localhost/index.php` instead of current page (without any parameters)?

Comment: you want to disable `#hashtag` in URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable updating URL with `#hashtag`, change default of `changePage` which handles pages transition before loading jQuery Mobile script in `<head>`.

> **Demo**: #Hashtag ([Disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2EYfp/show/) / [Enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2EYfp/3/show/))

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
     $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    });
 </script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each click event of the link / button fire the following...
To only remove the value, not the hash

`window.location.hash = ""`

...............................................................

This will completely remove the hash and value.

`window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))`

** Implementation **

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
});
```

Comment: how to do this? use $("a").click(function(){ window.location.href.split('#')[0] });

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Omar's excellent answer, you could disable the `changeHash` option when you're traversing from `#page1` to `#page2`, if you want this feature to be limited to only that point. Use `changePage` like this :

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
```