# How to prevent hash changes in jquery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a web site which is populated with articles. Clicking on an article takes you to a page and that's basically it. The problem is that I want to use jquery-mobile and since I pasted it into the head of my files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#index", {transition: "slide",reverse: true,changeHash: false});
    });
</script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

,linking the user to the articleDetail page doesn't work anymore. I saw that the URL doesn't accept the hashtag sign (#).

For example:

```
<a href="www.myPage.com/#detail/e98eee7e-5032-4d16-8c69-a441af018b8b"</a>
```

I expect a user to be redirected to this page with that exact same path, but jquery-mobile changes it to:

www.myPage.com/detail/e98eee7e-5032-4d16-8c69-a441af018b8b

and because of that nothing happens. I only get an output in the console:

GET www.myPage.com/detail/e98eee7e-5032-4d16-8c69-a441af018b8b 404 (Not Found)

Please help!

Comment: have you tried adding `data-ajax=false` anchor link?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't fix the problem. I changed the initialization of jquery and jquery-mobile a little bit and it solved the problem, but only partially. I updated my code and with this the redirect happens but only after you click a link for the second time! Really weird...

Comment: `data-rel=external` could solve the problem as well.

Comment: tried both data-ajax and data-external :/

Comment: ok try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111862/1771795

Comment: Still nothing :(...thanks for trying to help though!!

Answer (score 4):

Include these functions in your script:

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

This is defined by jquery mobile to handle hash enabled links