# jQuery mobile: convert hashes into full URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm currently using the jQuery mobile plugin to allow slick slide transitions between pages, these work great, perfect in fact! The only problem is, as I already have a hashchange function on the site I'm building, the hashchange events in the jQuery mobile transitions are breaking this function.
I've read the documentation and seen the `pushState plugin` that can convert the long hash based URL's into full document paths, but implemented like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't seem to be working and hashes are still being added, I'm assuming hashes can in fact be removed, e.g. from `www.website.com/#hash` to `www.website.com/hash` ? That's what I gathered the above function would do but it doesn't seem to work, if at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111862/1771795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
});
```

**OR**

```
<script>
//(default: true)
$.mobile.changePage( "../test.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
</script>
```

Comment: that's close although this is just stripping the hash from the URL instead of converting the hash into a full URL