# How to handle browser refresh while jqm-popup is open

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page, that uses a jqm-popup to display some content.

when the popup is opened, jqm appends a hash to the url: www.myjqm_page.com/**#&ui-state=dialog**.

Now if, while that popup is open, I refresh the browser, I get a broken site.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: you can disable hashchange completely. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111862/1771795

Comment: I have already built too much of the jqm-site around hashtag functionality to disable it.

Comment: I suppose maybe disabling hashtag-append whenever I do something like open a popup ... of course if the url already has a hashtag, when I open a popup, I will want it to leave the current hashtag in place, only NOT appending additional popup-related params. ... ... ... now the question: how to do that, other than url-sniffing.

Comment: I dont think its possible to disable hash change for popups only, unlike dialogs, you have `changeHash: false` option.